# What is the source of Hopf's (boundary) lemma?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request

In an introductory course on PDE's I got as a project to prove and present a version of [Hopf's (boundary) lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_lemma). Namely:

> Let $\Omega \subset R^{d}$ be an non-empty open connected set with a
> twice differentiable boundary. Let $u\in C^{2}(\Omega) \cap
> > C^{1}(\bar{\Omega})$ be a subharmonic function ($\Delta u \geq 0)$. If
> there exists a $M\geq 0$ such that $u(x) < M$ for all $x\in \Omega$
> and $u(x_{0}) = M$ for some $x_{0}$ on the boundary of $\Omega$ then
> the outward normal derivative at $x_{0}$ $(\nabla u(x_{0})\cdot n)$ is
> stricly positive.

Where can I find the original source of Hopf's lemma? I have looked trough Evans - Partial Differential Equations (second edition) and some notes written by professor John K. Hunter at UC Davis, but have been unable to make any progress.